# Why mozilla asks for plugin, on embed html code

Tags: javascript, html, css, mozilla

I have used embed src in a part of my  project, but when it get loaded in mozilla it asks for plugin does not show any content, while it is smooth in other browsers and display all content of embed.

```
<table width="89%" border="0" align="center" id="activity_gallery" style="background-image:url(images/background/bg2_2.jpg)">
    <tr >
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="">
            <embed src="gallery/activity/trk/trk.html" width="280" height="350"><br></embed>
        </td>
        <td width="">
            <embed src="gallery/activity/rope/rope.html" width="280" height="350"></embed>
        </td>
        <td width="">
            <embed src="gallery/activity/rock/rock.html" width="280" height="350"> </embed>
        </td>
        <td width="">
            <embed src="gallery/activity/group/rock.html" width="280" height="350"></embed>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

please suggest me how to make it relax for mozilla and IE both.

Comment: I don't think you should be using the `<embed>` tag. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am calling html page via embed in my index.html

Comment: What's the problem with `iframe` if all your pages are part of your website only.

Comment: i frame include border while embed not. and it has been used sucesfully, as i am comfortable with embed

Comment: remove the border then.

Comment: please suggest me how to remove border of iframe

Comment: ok thanks it works smoothly and boss accepted iframe.... thanks a lot for your idea

Comment: Add `border:none;` in css of `iframe`

Answer (score 4):

The `<embed>` tag is for plugins, as you can read in its [MDN webpage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed). If other browsers have allowed non-standard behavior for this tag, that is not a Firefox issue. You can use iframe without borders in order to show a seamless page:

With CSS:

```
iframe {
    border: none;
}
```

**UPDATE**

[W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-embed-element) does not forbid its use for HTML elements (bold are mine):

> The embed element provides an integration point for an external
>   **(typically non-HTML)** application or interactive content.

Maybe you can make it work using a proper content type, using the type attribute with something like `type="text/html"`

Comment: Yessss. That edit is it. *"..integration point for an external (typically non-html).."* is the key. For HTML documents one doesn't need integration point as it is already available thru iframes. But for non-html ones like flash etc.. to be able to use Javascript on those.. integration point is needed which embed provides. +1 for the edit.